# Redux-form custom select not using first value

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using react-redux and redux-form for my new project. When I create a custom select Field, it never passes the first option value (that is already "selected") to the handleSubmit function. Only when I manually select avalue, it passes the option value correctly.

Custom select:

```
const Select = ({ input, options, disabled }) => (
  <div>
    <select {...input} disabled={disabled}>
      { options.map(option =>
        <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
          {option.label}
        </option>
      )}
    </select>
  </div>
);
```

Form Component:

```
function RegisterForm({ handleSubmit, titles }) {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
      <Field name="title" options={titles} component={Select} />

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

RegisterForm.propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  titles: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'register'
})(RegisterForm);
```

Do I have to initialize the select from the redux state? Or is there another way to force the first value to be the initial value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to initialize your form.

1. Use the *initializeForm* function provided by redux-form, which is passed by props:

```js
componentWillMount () {
  this.props.initialize({
    title: 'Codifly'
  });
}
```

See docs: http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/docs/api/ActionCreators.md/

2. Pass default values using *initialValues*:

```js
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'register',
  initialValues: {
    title: 'Codifly'
  }
})(RegisterForm);
```

http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/docs/api/Props.md/

I hope this helps!